# Multiple questions on Abstract Class

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I have multiple questions on Abstract Class like

1. Why .NET compiler doesn't put any restriction on declaring a public constructor in Abstract class?
2. What's the significance of having internal constructor in Abstract class?
3. Why compiler allows declaring static constructor in Abstract class. In which scenario its useful.

Comment: If you're talking about appropriate language/s like C#, VB then, please tag the question appropriately with relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

> Why .NET compiler doesn't put any restriction on declaring a public
>   constructor in Abstract class?

See next.

> What's the significance of having internal constructor in Abstract
>   class?

If you want to force the concrete class to be located within the same module of the Abstract one.
Avoiding to have the child in an external module, in order to have control on those latter.

> Why compiler allows declaring static constructor in Abstract class? In which scenario its useful?

Static constructor are like initialization blocks in Java: Run some codes only on the first instantiation of the class, no matter if the code is based on the abstract or concrete (child) class.

Comment: Thanks for answers the queries, but still its not clear to me why .NET compiler doesn't put any restriction on declaring a public constructor in Abstract class?